# How to create a dictionary from a list of strings with same key, value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, dictionary

I have a list of strings with no duplicate elements and I need to generate a dictionary with elements of this list as key and values of this dictionary.

List:
`file_names = ['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'ad', 'rsb']`

Desired dictionary:

```
file_names = {'a': 'a', 'bb':'bb', 'ccc': 'ccc', 'ad': 'ad', 'rsb':'rsb'}
```

I want each element of list be as the key and also exactly have that element as it's value for that key. What is the best (most fast) way for generating such a dictionary in python specifically python 2?

Comment: `print(dict(zip(file_names, file_names)))` ?

Comment: Or: `{fn:fn for fn in file_names}`

Comment: Besides, why would you need such dict?

Comment: I have a list with a great amount of elements and I need to loop over it to check some things and this gets slow for great amount of elements. Therefore I want to covert it to a dictionary to improve my script performance.

Comment: What's the point of having a dictionary whose values are equal to keys? It's much faster just to use the key, instead of getting the value which is equal to the key.

Comment: Do mean it's not need to have such a dictionary and any generated dictionary can solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider using a `set` instead if all you wish to do is check if an element is in a collection. This gives you `O(1)` complexity for membership tests. You can convert a `list` to a `set` by doing

```
file_names = set(['a', 'bb', 'ccc', 'ad', 'rsb'])
file_names = set(file_names)
```

Then, you can check for membership by simply doing

```
if file_name in file_names:
```

Comment: Making a set from list also takes O(n) time.

Comment: Yes but the semantic intention of OP's dictionary is only for membership tests and not key/value lookups, thus the recommendation of a set. The point of discussion isn't the data structure creation time but rather the repeated access efficiency

Comment: If the downvoter could specify any shortcomings of this answer, I would be happy to correct them

Comment: I need to check membership as you mentioned before and I just create the data structure once before looping over it but what about the data structure creation speed and also is set faster than dictionaries in member checking operation?

Comment: Well you shouldn't even be worrying about the efficiency of set vs dict. The ***entire*** point of set is for membership tests. Using dict for solely membership tests is unidiomatic